# Running 10 instances of AsyncTask but loading dialog appeared only for last one

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an AsyncTask Class for running web methods. I want to show Loading dialog when receiving web method results. The problem is when I'm trying to execute this class 10 times for then web methods, program freezes and after about 30 seconds dialog appears for about 5 secs! what's wrong with my code?
My Async Class:

```
public class AsyncCallWs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    public String methodName="";
    private WebService ws;
    private ArrayList<ServiceParam> paramsList;
    private boolean hasParams; 

    public AsyncCallWs(Activity activity,String methodName) {
        xLog.position();
        try {
            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            this.methodName = methodName;
            hasParams = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public AsyncCallWs(Activity activity,String methodName,ArrayList<ServiceParam> params) {
        xLog.position();
        try {
            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.paramsList = params;
            hasParams = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage(PersianReshape.reshape("Loading..."));
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        xLog.position();
        String result = "No async task result!";
        try {
            ws = new WebService(PublicVariable.NAMESPACE, PublicVariable.URL);
            if (!hasParams){
                result = ws.CallMethod(methodName);
            }
            else{
                xLog.info("THIS METHOD IS: "+ methodName);
                result = ws.CallMethod(methodName,paramsList);
                xLog.info("THIS RESULT IS: "+ result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            xLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        xLog.position();

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        xLog.info("Output of current AsyncTask is:"+ result);
    }
}
```

This is my Sync Function to run all of my web methods:

```
    public void doSync(String method){
        xLog.position();
        AsyncCallWs t;
        ArrayList<ServiceParam> serviceParams = new ArrayList<ServiceParam>();
        String result="";

        Settings settings = new Settings(activity);
        PublicVariable.pGuid = Login(settings.getValue("Username"), settings.getValue("Password"));  

        xLog.info("pGuid in doSync is:" + PublicVariable.pGuid);
        serviceParams.add(new ServiceParam("pGuid", PublicVariable.pGuid, String.class));



        if (method=="all" || method=="person"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetPersonInfo",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                xLog.info("Sync Person=>"+ result);
                String fields[] = result.split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                Person person = new Person(activity,fields);
                person.empty();
                person.insert();
                settings.update("PersonId",String.valueOf(person.getId()));
                PublicVariable.personId = person.getId();
                xLog.info("Person inserted...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="personImage"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetPersonImage",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    settings.update("picture", result);
                    xLog.info("Picture updatted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO PERSON IMAGE FOUND!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="lawyers"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetLawyers",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                xLog.info("Sync Lawyer=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                    String fields[];
                    Lawyer lawyer= new Lawyer(activity);
                    lawyer.empty();
                    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                        fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                        lawyer = new Lawyer(activity, fields);
                        lawyer.insert();
                    }
                    xLog.info("Lawyers inserted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO LAWYER FOUND!");
            }catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="news"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetNews",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                String fields[];
                Log.d("Ehsan","Sync News=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                    News news = new News(activity);
                    news.empty();
                    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                        fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                        news= new News(activity,fields);
                        news.insert();
                    }
                    xLog.info("News inserted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO NEWS FOUND!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="messages"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetMessagesInbox ",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                Log.d("Ehsan","Sync message Inbox=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                    String fields[];
                    Message message = new Message(activity);
                    message.empty();
                    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                        fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                        message= new Message(activity,fields);
                        message.insert();
                    }
                    xLog.info("Inbox messages inserted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO MESSAGES FOUND!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetMessagesOutbox ",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                Log.d("Ehsan","Sync message Outbox=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                String fields[];
                Message message = new Message(activity);
                message.empty();
                for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                    fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                    message= new Message(activity,fields);
                    message.insert();

                }
                xLog.info("Outbox messages inserted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO MESSAGES FOUND!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="requests"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetAllRequests",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                Log.d("Ehsan","Sync share buy sell requests=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                String fields[];
                Share share = new Share(activity);
                share.empty();
                for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                    fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                    share= new Share(activity,fields);
                    share.insert();
                }
                xLog.info("Shares inserted...");
                }
                else
                    xLog.error("NO MESSAGES FOUND!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (method=="all" || method=="financials"){
            try {
                t = new AsyncCallWs(activity,"GetFinancials",serviceParams);
                result = t.execute().get();
                Log.d("Ehsan","Sync Financials=>"+ result);
                if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.RECORD_SPLITTER);
                    String fields[];
                    Financial financial = new Financial(activity);
                    financial.empty();
                    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                        fields = records[i].split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                        financial= new Financial(activity,fields);
                        financial.insert();
                    }
                    xLog.info("Financials inserted...");
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("Ehsan", "NOT FINANCIALS FOUND!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                xLog.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats your prob tell it short and sweet

Comment: It's clear! I want to show loading dialog during executing web method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `doSync(...)` method. You are starting each AsyncTaskwith `result = t.execute().get();`. This is a blocking call. The UI thread will freeze at this point until the AsyncTask returns a result. Just execute the thread and parse the result back to the UI thread in the `AsyncTask#onPostExecute(...)` method using a method of the UI thread.

Your AsyncTask should end up this way:

```
...
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    xLog.position();
    dialog.dismiss();

    onWSResult(result);

    xLog.info("Output of current AsyncTask is:"+ result);
}
...
```

And your activity should offer the associated method:

```
private void onWSResult(String result){
   ...process the results here...
}
```

Furthermore, why all your if clauses start with method == 'all' and contain an ||?

Comment: I don't want to move my code into my Async class. is there any way to do it without moving the code into Async class?

Comment: I edited my answer. Anyway, why you want to use Async in a blocking manner? Is it just to prevent Android to throw an expception that there are network operations on the UI thread. That's not the way to go ;)

Comment: Because I want to program in object oriented way and I don't know how to do it in another way!  is it a good idea to have an Async task for executing all of web methods or having a separated class for general purpose?

Comment: This is object oriented and AsyncTask is the right tool for this purpose. Get familiar with the concepts of threads. Imagine it like different spaces where your objects are living. And your described behaviour happens because you build a stable connection between the spaces. Indeed, what you need is a message based connection between the spaces and thats the way I showed you in my initial comment.